# Remove the field requirement after selecting the tag by the user

Tags: javascript, php

I want to require tag selection in the question form for users, I required the field (In the tag field, after typing, the item list is opened and the tag should be selected from the available options.)
But after selecting the tag from the list of items, again the form will ask to fill the tag field.
But I want the users no longer need to fill in the field after selecting the tag from the list of items.

**set validate form condition:**

```
            this.submit_validator = $("form#submit_question").validate({
            ignore: "",
            rules: {
                post_title: {
                    required :true,
                    maxlength: qa_front.texts.max_lengh,
                },
                question_category: "required",
                post_content: "required",
                questions_tag: "required",
            },
```

**AND TEMPLATE TAG:**

```
 if( !function_exists('qa_tag_template') ):
  function qa_tag_template(){
    ?>
    <script type="text/template" id="tag_item">

        <input type="hidden" name="tags[]" value="{{= stripHTML(name) }}" />
        {{= stripHTML(name) }} <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="delete"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>

    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function stripHTML(html)
        {
           var tmp = document.createElement("DIV");
           tmp.innerHTML = html;
           return tmp.textContent||tmp.innerText;
        }
    </script>
    <?php
}
 endif;
```

**Please note the shot:**

[image: image 1]

Comment: please help me. :(